# I'm completely confused with Python's directories, virtual environments and file handling

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code

First off let me apologize in case none of this makes sense to you but I will try my best explaining my problem.

I'm new to Python and I have been constantly dealing with files and programs that don't run, confusing terminal errors and more.
I've been trying to follow a tutorial which consists of accessing a remote MySql database using python but when I try to execute the program (just like the guy in the tutorial) nothing happens. This isn't the first time something like this happens as I have barely been able to use any modules because the program can't find them. I've also encountered that (inside) VSCode's terminal show's me a bunch of directories which I have no clue why they're there or if that might be the cause of all these problems:
As you can see here right after running the program, the terminal opens up and by default shows multiple directories, and if I'm not wrong there should only be one? [image: As you can see here right after running the program, the terminal opens up and by default shows multiple directories, and if I'm not wrong there should only be one?]

This is what happens when I try to execute the program (nothing happens) and as I've seen in the tutorial, a lot of data should start appearing but the only thing happening is that a new line is created. [image: This is what happens when I try to execute the program (nothing happens) and as I've seen in the tutorial, a lot of data should start appearing but the only thing happening is that a new line is created.]

I could really use some help, this is not allowing me to make any progress and I'm starting to get frustrated because I can't even find any help online.

Thank you and sorry if my problem isn't very clear but even I don't know what the problem is.

NOTE THAT THOSE ARE NOT MY PERSONAL DETAILS IT'S FROM AN OPEN DATABASE

Comment: PLEASE TELL ME THOSE USERNAME AND PASSWORD ARE FAKE AND NOT REAL or did you just expose it to here on purpose?

Comment: please post code only as text and without your passwrods and login

Comment: and also _"the terminal opens up and by default shows multiple directories"_, its not mutiple directories instead it is your code execution and i think your SQL query is syntatically wrong too, did you mean `SELECT * FROM DICTIONARY`

Comment: The user and password are from an open database used in a tutorial on Udemy

Comment: and you dont have to say `query = cursor.execute(....)` just mention `cursor.execute(...)` instead, there is not much other mistake i can notice here

Comment: Please mind that all that code is written entirely as I've been following on a tutorial. Any ideas on what could be wrong with the code execution thing?

Comment: Nope, i dont see any problem with the code here, it should be printing out something atleast, dont know why. Maybe try restarting VSCODE

Answer (score 0):

Please change

> SELECT  =  FROM DICTIONARY

to

> SELECT  *  FROM DICTIONARY

on your query.